# What is this 'bracket assignment' syntax better known as?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I recently encountered this syntax:

```
UIView *view=({
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    view;
});
```

This might well be a duplicate but I don't know what to search for.

- What is this syntax known as?
- Has it always been supported or is it a recent addition?
- Is it considered good or bad practice?
- Are there any gotchas?

Comment: This probably works as a function, returning the view after creating it and setting the background colour. Never seen something similar :)

Comment: @Basheer_CAD - Interesting, but there is no `return` statement, so surely its not a function?

Comment: @MartinR - Ah cool thanks! So its part of C.  Do you have any info on the best practices of this technique?

Comment: @Robert: As explained in the GCC docs, it allows you to introduce local variables just for the computation of an expression. I don't think that there are any "gotchas", and it is more a matter of personal preference. In this particular case I do not see any advantage and would not use it.